# What cards transfer mana from colorless to any color?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-manabase

So all I need to know is if there are any known MTG cards that say "pay one colorless mana: produce one mana of any color."

Comment: Welcome to B&CG.SE! I've updated your title so that it better reflects your question. Hopefully this will clarify for users on the home page.

Comment: Do you really mean specifically colorless mana, or just generic?

Comment: This is basically asking for a subset of what [this question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/20472/cards-changing-mana-color) asked for.

Comment: Also might be worth mentioning something like [mtg:Manalith] or [mtg:Opaline Unicorn] which tap for any color

Answer (score 1):

For once per turn effects, something like [Mana Prism](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mana%20Prism) or [Prophetic Prism](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Prophetic%20Prism) do that. For permanent "spend mana as if it were any kind", something like [Mycosynth Lattice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mycosynth%20Lattice) might be your only option.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Using Wizards [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/), you can search for permanents that will filter mana for you. Via Advanced Search, use the following in the Rules Text Box.

", {T}: Add one mana"

Add it in its entirety, including the quotations.

Comment: This search doesn't _quite_ correspond to what the question is asking. Did you mean it just as an example?

Comment: @DavidZ, no. The question hasn't been clarified on whether it is specifically looking for a card that turns "Colorless" mana into Colored Mana. There isn't an effect that acts as a infinite filter for colored mana. Short the Mycosynth Lattice, these are the closest cards that provide the desired effect.

Comment: "There isn't an effect that acts as a infinite filter for colored mana" isn't exactly true. Bog Initiate filters an arbitrary amount of mana into black mana. Farrelite Priest does the same with white (with caveats). And Orochi Leafcaller filters an arbitrary amount of green mana into mana of any color.

Comment: @murgatroid99, Neither of those support the transforms colorless mana into "mana of any color."